# Equivalent of Perl's Tie::Hash in PHP

Tags: php, tie

I've been searching for information on this with no luck. Maybe I'm not searching for the right thing.

In Perl, you can create `tied` objects, like scalars, hashes or arrays, and define what happens when you interact with your object. For example, you can tie a hash against a database, and have a database record automagically changed as soon as you assign or modify a value in that hash.

Is there something in PHP I can use for the same purpose? (not only for databases, but to trigger actions when a variable is changed/accessed, etc.)

Comment: The closest thing would be [magic getters/setters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what Tie::Hash does it's sort of like an implementation of an internalized observer and unfortunately PHP doesn't offer anything like that, especially on things like scalar values and arrays.

It sounds dangerously close to black magic :)

Comment: Yes, it's pretty amazing. PHP should implement it too. :-)